# Get the "default value" of an object's type in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I want to get the "default value" of an object based on its type in clojure. For example, it might work like this:

```
(default-value 15) ;; => 0
(default-value "hi") ;; => ""
```

In both cases, it takes the type of the value, and returns a "blank" instance of that value's type. The best I can come up with is

```
(defn default-value [x] (.newInstance (.getClass x)))
```

But this doesn't work on numbers:

```
repl=> (.newInstance (.getClass 1))

NoSuchMethodException java.lang.Long.<init>()  java.lang.Class.getConstructor0 (Class.java:3082)
```

Comment: A numbers "default" value depends on how the number is used. Eg. 0 is for addition and 1 is used when doing multiplication.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like multimethods could be a good fit:

```
(defmulti   getNominalInstance (fn [obj] (.getClass obj)))
(defmethod  getNominalInstance java.lang.Long   [obj] (Long. 0))
(defmethod  getNominalInstance java.lang.String [obj] "")

(prn :long    (getNominalInstance 5))
(prn :string  (getNominalInstance "hello"))

;=> :long 0
;=> :string ""
```

The problem is that Long only has 2 constructors, which take either a primitive long or a string, respectively.

```
Long(long value) - Constructs a newly allocated Long object 
that represents the specified long argument.

Long(String s) - Constructs a newly allocated Long object 
that represents the long value indicated by the String parameter.
```

It isn't legal Java to say "new Long()", which is what `newInstance()` does. So, you have to do it manually with `defmulti` or equivalent.

Comment: I ended up going this route, except I used `defprotocol` and `extend-protocol` instead of multi methods, as they're intended for single argument type based dispatch cases like this 

Answer (score 2):

There's not really any such thing as a "default value" for a type, unless you are looking for the way that Java default-initializes stuff in constructors when you don't provide an explicit value. That's just:

- boolean=>false
- number=>0
- object=>null

If you want something more sophisticated (eg, string=>"") you will have to write it yourself, by dispatching somehow on the type of the object into code you control.

Comment: Agreed - Clojure has no concept of a "default value" for a type so it's up to you to build a conditional to make something if you want it.